# Porque me sale undefined variable?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, web

como podría solucionar este problema:

Notice: Undefined variable: correo_err in C:\xampp\htdocs\Colbun\recupcontra.php on line 18
Notice: Undefined variable: contrasena_err in C:\xampp\htdocs\Colbun\recupcontra.php on line 20
Notice: Undefined variable: recontrasena_err in C:\xampp\htdocs\Colbun\recupcontra.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined variable: match_err in C:\xampp\htdocs\Colbun\recupcontra.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined variable: msg in C:\xampp\htdocs\Colbun\recupcontra.php on line 28
Notice: Undefined variable: error in C:\xampp\htdocs\Colbun\recupcontra.php on line 28

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Iniciar Sesión</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="contenedor__todo">
            
        <!--Formulario de registro y login-->
        <div class="contenedor__login-register">
            <!--Login-->
            <form action="php/recuperar_contrasena_be.php" method="POST" class="formulario__login" style="margin-top: 800px; margin-left: 200px;">
                <h2>Recuperar Contraseña</h2>
                <span><?php echo $correo_err; ?></span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su correo electrónico" name="correo" id="correo">
                <span><?php echo $contrasena_err; ?></span>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese su nueva contraseña" name="contrasena" id="contrasena">
                <span><?php echo $recontrasena_err; echo $match_err; ?></span>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Re-Ingrese nuevamente su contraseña" name="recontrasena" id="recontrasena">
                <center><button name="Btnlogin">Enviar</button></center>
                <br><br>
                <center><a href="index.php">Regresar al inicio de sesión</a></center>
                <br><br>
                <p><?php echo $msg; echo $error; ?></p>
            </form>
            <!--Registro-->
            
        </div>
    </div>
    </main>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y esas variables de dónde llegan?

Comment: @BetaM de recuperar_contrasena_be.php, lo nombré en el action

Comment: No así no funciona, la URL de action es a donde viajan los datos y no de dónde los tomas, por eso te da ese error

Comment: @BetaM en ese caso como podria llamar las variables que se encuentran en el otro archivo?

Comment: Con un require al inicio del documento